# How to subscribe to Amazon SNS topic with e-mail endpoint via e-mail?

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using Amazon SNS to send simple messages to users. I'm using several topic with different endpoints including E-Mail.

Right now subscribtion to topics is handled by the Java back-end via AWS Java SDK. I get user's address and create a subscription via `AmazonSNSClient`. The user has to confirm his subscription. Later or he can unsubscribe just by clicking a link in the mail sent my Amazon SNS.

**What I was wondering - isn't is possible to let users subscribe via e-mail?**
Like sending an e-mail to `subscribe@....amazonaws.com` with the ARN of the topic as subject - or similar?

I could then just display a `mailto:` link as a subscription link in my application which has a few advantages in my case.

Comment: Is it currently possible? No, it's not. From a security perspective, it's not difficult to forge the 'from' address, which could open up a whole lot of abuse with that approach.  I'd recommend pinging AWS support and discussing options for what you want to implement directly with them - perhaps there are some other services/options that can help?

Comment: @Chris Most mailing lists have this option. You still need to confirm the subscription, I fail to see why should it not be safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you comparing SNS to mailing lists. What you need to realize is that SNS isn't designed for use as a mailing list, and is indeed extremely terrible at sending any sort of nice looking email to end users. I would only recommend using SNS emails for things like system outage alerts to your administrative staff. I think this confusion comes in because the SNS mobile push feature is designed to push messages to end users, but the other SNS notification methods (email, http, SMS, SQS, Lambda) aren't designed for end-users at all.

If you want to stick with AWS services, then you could build a newsletter feature on top of SES, or use something like Sendy. I would personally recommend looking outside AWS for a full featured email service like MailChimp or SendGrid.

Comment: I'm using SNS to send notifications about health status of around 3000 elevator/escalator facilities. So it's exactly outage alerts. These emails are one-liners which don't need to be good looking. From my point of view, SNS suits the task pretty well, I don't see enough added value to move to anything else. My whole question was if I could just render a `mailto:...` link or do I need some back-end to create subscriptions.

Comment: No it's not possible to subscribe via email, as other people have already replied. You responded to them by comparing SNS to mailing list services, which is why I posted my answer, explaining that Amazon didn't build SNS to be used as a mailing list service.

Comment: _"My whole question was if I could just render a mailto:... link or do I need some back-end to create subscriptions."_ - you'll need to write your backend to create the subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribing to email notifications by email would be open to misuse - just find a way to construct an email with a forged `from` address and you'll have hundreds of subscribers.

So this clearly is not safe from a security perspective - which is probably whay it's not there in the first place.

Comment: But I don't see why subscribing by sending mail "is not safe from a security perspective" as most of the mailing lists out there have a "subscribe by send a mail" option.  
See [Apache Mailing Lists](http://apache.org/foundation/mailinglists.html). You still need to confirm the subscription, of course.

Comment: Just because it **exists** doesn't mean it's a good idea. I clearly dislike using email for registration as forging is extremly simple.

Comment: This may or may not be a good idea depending on the use case. You've brought a safety concern an I'm trying to figure out if it is correct or not. As long as I know target's mail address(es), I can start hundreds of subscriptions for mailing lists and it does not matter if I do it it via e-mail or web forms (as long as they don't use captchas and many don't). But unlike you were saying, I won't get hundreds of subscribers if they don't confirm subscriptions (which I can't forge). So I really don't see why subscribing by sending a mail is generally less safe. Where's my mistake?

Comment: If I understand your proposed process: (1) User sends email to `subscribe@...`, (2) Some system turns that email into a subscribe request, and attempts to subscribe that email to SNS, (3) SNS sends out confirmation email. (4) User confirms subscription.  Your original question *implies* you're asking "can SNS be system #2 in that process" - *no, it can't*.  You can build something that does this yourself, but as Mark mentions in his answer - "_[SNS] is indeed extremely terrible at sending any sort of nice looking email to end users_"

Comment: @Chris Yes, this is the proposed process. Returning to your original answer, do you see security risk there? Concerning *nice looking email* - this is not my use case. I send status update notifications of elevator/escalator facilities, they are simple one-liners.

Comment: I don't see a major issue with that - we interpreted it originally as subscription with no confirmation (treating "confirmation" as it came from a specific email address).  In any case, you'd have to implement such a component (that receives email and subscribes the user to SNS) yourself, as SNS doesn't do this.